# How to discover a BLE service on nRF connect app using flutter_blue_plus plugin

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to a BLE service running on nRF connect app (phone A) to a flutter application running on another phone 'B' using the flutter_blue_plus plugin.

I advertised packets on the nRF Connect app and I'm able to discover my phone in the Bluetooth scan of the flutter application, but the services list is empty.

I just printed out the scan result.

```
var subscription = conn.scanResults.listen((results) {
for (ScanResult r in results) {
print('${r.device.name} : ${r.device}');} });
```

Output - I/flutter (16345):  : BluetoothDevice{id: 04:C9:61:98:0A:87, name: , type: BluetoothDeviceType.unknown, isDiscoveringServices: false, _services: []

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIL44.png)

I'm attempting to connect to the service running phone, discover the service and access the service data.